# Creating an associated model along with main model in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following code to create a drop down in a view to associate a model with another one. This works but I have to prepopulate the tasks in the database. I'd like to be able to create tasks during the creation of a project instead of just selecting ones that are already there.

```
  <%= f.label :task %>
  <%= f.collection_select( :task_id,
              Task.all,
              :id, :name, {selected: @project.task_id, include_blank: false}) %>
```

From what I understand I'm going to have to do this in the controller as well, but a lot of the code I've seen is out of date and I want to do it the Rails 4 way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a new project & trying to create tasks too, you'll need to use a [`nested model form`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) ([`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)):

```
#app/models/Project.rb
def Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tasks
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end

#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.tasks.build #-> do this for as many tasks as you want
end

def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.save
end

private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:new, :project, :attrs, tasks_attributes: [:task_name])
end


#app/views/projects/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |t| %>
       <%= t.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```